# How to change the selected text color In Internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have seen in many weblogs when we select text the background color of the text changes rather than usual blue. [This Tech](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html)
Works in Firefox and Safari, is there any method available for Internet Explorer?

Comment: doesn't look promising, IE seems set in its ways

http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/ie6/selectcolor.aspx

maybe javascript?

Comment: The SELECTED selector in the original question works fine in IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done in IE with pure CSS and I don't know of any pre-packaged JS that will get the job done, either.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
<style>
::selection {color:red;background:yellow;}
::-moz-selection {color:red;background:yellow;}
</style>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_selection

Answer (score 0):

Not supported on IE as far as I know. Unless there's some clever hack I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be difficult to emulate

- You could try and set a background colour for the text selected, but the default blue highlighting will probably ruin your effect
- The browser would probably choke on some systems when someone is selecting a lot of text and changing their selection rapidly.

I think you should use CSS for the browsers that support it, and wait patiently for IE to adopt this.

Answer (score 0):

You could always remove it.

```
    

        if (window.getSelection) {
          if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
            window.getSelection().empty();
          } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
          }
        } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
          document.selection.empty();
        }
```