# Changing colour on text selection in IE<9

Tags: html, css

How to change the colour of text when its selected by css/javascript in IE<9? As far as I know the `::selection` doesn't work in IE<9. Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824383/how-to-change-the-selected-text-color-in-internet-explorer

Comment: ah thanks. Wonder how I missed it before!! Still it says its not possible in IE. It seems nothing can be done for IE<9...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html) confirms this isn't supported in IE. I know of no alternative to this (CSS or JS) for IE.

Comment: This is right. IE8 and lower doesn't support this. So stop trying :D