# is there a way to change the background color when an user select text in browser ( for IE9 below versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

We all know that when we select a text portion in browser, its background color changed to blue. I have used the ::selection pseudo-element to change the background color like below code.

```
::selection {
    background: pink;color: yellow;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: pink;color: yellow;
}
```

see my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh5As/1/) 
but ::selection doesn't support for IE9 below versions.Please check the **Browser compatibility** table provided [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3a%3aselection) once. I need to apply the same properties in IE9 below versions. Can anyone tell me the alternate way for doing this one.   Thanks in advance

Comment: This was asked earlier in the week... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249116/changing-colour-on-text-selection-in-ie9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824383/how-to-change-the-selected-text-color-in-internet-explorer
Have a look here. Have been asked before

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I have seen many sites, I couldn't find any solution but I need to apply same properties for all browsers including IE9 below versions. I can't change the requirement. Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

one way you can do it with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
$("#textfield").focus(function () {
$('.class').css(' background-color','#ffe823');
});
});
```

```
<input type="text" class="class" name="textfield" id="textfield" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But if user select the text using tab and arrow keys, then...

Comment: I have tried your answer. When I select any portion of text, the entire background color is changed. But I need to change the background of selected text only. this is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VVrTW/1/) which I have tried using your answer

Comment: now try this i have edit the code and let me know it works perfect or not

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is also not working, see this once http://jsfiddle.net/VVrTW/3/

Comment: have you included jquery in your header ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10482/discussion-between-pravallika69-and-dianuj)