# Change default selected text color on webpage content

Tags: javascript, php, css

In a webpage when we select any content it will show blue color for selection.
How to Change this default selected  color on webpage  with other custom color ?

Comment: Perhaps this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824383/how-to-change-the-selected-text-color-in-internet-explorer?rq=1 ... Moreover, this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_selection Not sure if it works in all browsers, though. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6XRrW/ .. EDIT: CHECK THIS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection --> it is NOT compatible with mobile browsers, apparently, but it seems to be working on all **modern browsers**. Table: http://prntscr.com/48f7m7

Comment: refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

Comment: thanks to all for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E2r2W/3/)

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```